# SSH autokiller for connections from other systems

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, macos

I was messing around with `ssh` and decided to write a python program that scans for any connections that aren't from the system, then terminates them. It works well for many connections from my iMac to my MacBook. A more in-depth explanation of the program is written at the top of the code. I'd appreciate feedback on any nitpicks you can find, since I threw this together in about thirty minutes. Any and all feedback is appreciated and considered.

**scanner.py**

```
""" Import Statements """
import os
import subprocess
import time

"""

Objective: Scan all connections to this computer, every two seconds, and if any are not
system, as in not `console` or `s000`, find the PID associated with the connection,
then terminate the connection with `kill -9 ...`

"""

def format_pid(text):
    """
    Formats the output to only include PIDS that are not from the system
    """
    ids = text.split("\n")
    all_ids = []
    del ids[0] #removes uptime stuff
    for line in ids:
        pid = line[:13]
        if pid[12:] != '0':
            all_ids.append(pid[:5])
    return all_ids

def get_pids():
    """ Returns all users logged into the computer """
    return format_pid(subprocess.Popen(['ps'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0])

def kill():
    """ Terminates all processes that are not system """
    processes = get_pids()
    for process in processes:
        if process: # Makes sure process isn't null/empty
            os.system('kill -9 ' + process)
            print("KILLED CONNECTION PROCESS: " + process)

    time.sleep(2)
    kill()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kill()
```

Comment: No time for a proper review, but you may be interested in [`psutil`](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace magic numbers like 13 there `line[:13]` with constansts. 
IMHO:

- rename `ids` to `lines`
- `all_ids` to `ids`
- `processes` to `pids`